# Setting settings in rails app, without storing values on db.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically I have an app that handles incoming email via Mailgun routes. Now depending on what address I receive the email, Mailgun makes a post request to the appropriate controller action, and basically dependant on which action it is, a field named department_id: needs to be assigned to the right department, so people of that department receive that email.

Now i know how to do this manually, and its working ok, but I wanted to make kind of a "Settings Screen" and you select which department should be selected when each action is called. Now i know i can create a db table and handle this, but is there a way to achieve this without creating a whole separate table?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to store the settings somewhere persistent. Why do you think the database is not the best storage for this?

Comment: This is a setting that would be changes oh so rarely. Also our ap db is growing fast, currently at 19+tables (in house admin app for managing orders, shops, tickets, time tracking etc) ...

Comment: If it changes so rarely that you want to hard-code it in source code, you could store it in a configuration file in source code, perhaps a yaml file with action-to-department mappings. Of course, you could also just hard-code it in the action itself. To change it, you'd have to change the settings in configuration file in source and re-deploy your app. That might be appropriate for your app.  I think those are your two options, hard-coding in source code (perhaps with a config file), or the db.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can keep the data in memory, but this is a **bad idea**, mainly because:

1. Unless you're running a single server process with a single thread, your app servers will have different copies of the data. The processes won't be able to keep these copies synchronized, and you won't be able to update them all at the same time.
2. It's inconsistent. Inter-process synchronization aside, all you need is a single server process with different data to make your app's logic inconsistent.
3. When the app restarts or crashes, you loose all the modifications.

This is exactly why we use DBs and other external data supports (redis, memcached, files, etc) to store data shared by different processes.

An *acceptable* solution is to add this kind of data to the source of your app, e.g. in a Rails initializer. However, the moment you try to change it at runtime you'll encounter the problems described above.